# Zend 2 sql query issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, zend-framework, pdo

3 framework and want to do simple sql. I have function like this but the problem is that I outputs
"SELECT `listings`.* FROM `listings` WHERE `listings_id` = '1' LIMIT '1'" I do not want the first listings just after select I want all the cols.

```
static $tableName = 'listings';

public function getListingsById($id){

    $select = new Select();
    $select->from(self::$tableName);
    $where = new Where();
    $where->equalTo('listings_id', $id);
    $select->where($where);
    $select->limit(1);

    echo $select->getSqlString($this->getAdapter()->getPlatform());
    return $this->selectWith($select);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT listings.* FROM listings` is the same as `SELECT * FROM listings` - both will give you all the columns from that table.